# Drupal 7 Commerce - What permissions do I need to set to give access to a specific role to view ANY order for administration?

Tags: 7, commerce, users

In drupal 7 commerce i setup a staff role to access and manage commerce orders, but they are getting an access denied even though i have all the Orders permissions checked off. Is there somewhere else I need to check off to enable permissions for a specific role?

> [image: Config screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how my permission look like --

> [image: Config screenshot]

As you can see, Site Admin & Shop Keeper can manage orders along with administrator(I have several kind of users). Site Admin & Shop Keeper doesn't have access to toolbar, so I have created a menu with name "Manage Order" & set it to the path "admin/commerce/orders"(I have several menu items of this kind).

Placed this menu in one region with permission set to be viewed only by these users type who are intended to use it. These users have permission to use admin theme, so they access it just like administer do by clicking on those menu item.